# accdb vs mdb. Which is faster/better?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Does anyone have any experience of using Access 2007 with the prior versions of Access (i.e. mdb files).

We have been upgraded, but are still using the mdb format. Some of our code (in particular Docmd.TransferDatabase acImportReport) are now incredibly slow.

I tried an initial test and converted our client mdb to accdb and the above TransferDatabase seemed to perform better.

I am now wondering whether we should bite the bullet and convert all the other files that make up the application. There is no need for replication or user-level security that appear to be the only limitations of the new version from the old. We have one client mdb, three backend databases and then 3000 mdbs each containing a single report (don't ask!).

Does the new version perform any faster than the old one - particularly over an already struggling network)?

Comment: MDB is a native format in Access 2007, so an MDB file is not a "prior version" file at all. Access 2000-, 2002-, 2003- and 2007-format MDBs are all native to Access 2007.

Comment: My guess is that the improvement in performance came from creating a new file. Try creating a new MDB and importing everything into it, and my bet is it will perform faster than your old MDB front end.

Comment: Made a new mdb in 2007 and imported the lot. Still faster using the accdb file....

Comment: Be aware that when you convert an mdb to accdb, Access will replace some references without asking. For example the goold old DAO will be replaced.

Answer (score 3):

Do anything new in accdb (interface wise); any new databases create in MS SQL Server.

Leave the existing stuff in mdb; if it is working now, why mess with it. Hardware upgrades will compensate for any performance degradation you are experiencing.

Sooner or later MS will announce they will stop supporting mdb in their current version of MS Access; at which point it is worth it to triage and start converting to the new format. But don't make the database accdb. Move it to something like MS SQL Server.

The reason why I would wait until you are forced by MS is that it is unlikely you will get approval from the purse string holders to make those changes now; but when you forced too, their purse strings loosen up.

Comment: Aaah. We would love to move to SQL Server, but we are working within the business area rather than the technology area. RAD developing if you like so we are limited to desktop tools such as Excel and Access...50+ users on a 500MB mdb over a shocking network - I am glad I am not one of the end users!

Comment: I say use ACCDB if ACCDB has features you really need (like Sharepoint integration). If not, stay with MDB even for new projects, because you can then run it on all previous versions of Access back to 2000, rather than worrying about everyone getting their workstations upgraded to A2007.

Comment: Thanks David (and re "native" vs "prior"). Everyone has been upgraded...and now they are looking at perhaps getting more RAM for all the PCs as well.

Comment: MT, SQL Server isn't necessarily the business solely of the tech area, just because it has the word Server in its name. Putting it on SQL Server may also improve things for them as well. Especially if the queries can run on the server before the data is passed back to the client.

Comment: @David W. Fenton: the accdb format is receiving bug fixes that the mdb format is not e.g. the DECIMAL sort bug (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837148) and MS doesn't publicize the fact so how would you ever know? That's why it's always best to go with the new format for new projects. The mdb format is officially deprecated other than for pre-Access2007 projects.

Comment: @CodeSlave: Most places that refuse to get SQL server do so because the business people can't (or won't) make room in their budget for a proper DB backend when they already have Access.

Comment: @A. Scagnelli, That's why we have the Express and Developer editions. However, given that they are willing to make a $100 investment per use to upgrade MS Office to a version with MS Access (over 50+ users), what's another $20-$30 per user for MS SQL as well ($4000-$6000). True, the business people might not see this immediately, but... that's just part of the job.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt very much that there is a lot of performance improvement in ACCDB vs MDB although I suppose individual functions could be better or worse.  I say this because the biggest bottleneck is usually network related.

I'd suggest running timing tests though.   Compare the two.  Make sure the MDB is in A2007 format though.  Exit the MDB/ACCDB between tests as otherwise Access may cache data.  Run the test several times and if any major differences keep rerunning it until you get three runs with about the same time.

Just curious though.  WHy do you folks do the Docmd.TransferDatabase acImportReport so much?  Or is that part of your 3000 MDBs with reports in them?

Comment: Spot on. It is part of our 3000 mdbs. We have an application that supports a lot of different reports for different clients. These are imported at runtime depending on the report that is being run. Originally these were all in one large mdb, but importing those was ridiculously slow once you had more than one connection to that database. Having separate databases for each rpt was much faster.

Comment: I think one of the guys played with making a library/mda for all the reports but without much luck. These reports have to be tweaked quite alot so we simply change the report on the network and the client picks up the new one. Personally I am not a big fan of the current set-up as we cannot use an mde, or even know that all of our code compiles.

Answer (score 2):

A quick test on a database with 187 medium-length scholarly references showed a reduction in size from 1,671,168 bytes to 1,306,624 as a .accdb file.

Here's an article with some pros & cons:

[Access File Formats: ACCDB vs MDB](https://www.thoughtco.com/access-file-formats-accdb-vs-mdb-1019506)

They point out with .accdb's, you can:

- Include attachments in your database
- Use multivalued fields
- Allow SharePoint and Outlook to trust these files, due to "[i]mprovements in the database security model [which] allow for the security validation of database files"
- Have supposed cryptography improvements due to use of the Windows Cryptographic API

Here's a M$ article that tells how to do attachments as database record fields:

[Attach files and graphics to the records in your database](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Attach-files-and-graphics-to-the-records-in-your-database-d40a09ad-a753-4a14-9161-7f15baad6dbd)

The first article also says: "There are also two limitations that you should consider when using ACCDB. ACCDB databases do not support user-level security or replication."  I made a copy of a database, and it opened, no problem - even in a different directory; so I don't know what you are missing out on in terms of replication.

Note: I was unable to Save As to convert it to a .accdb file, as given in the first article.  I did File | Save & Publish, and it let me.